# Python unittest loader very slow

Tags: python, unit-testing

I'm trying to run a suite of unit tests (Python 2.7) and most of the time is spent doing the discovery - about 16s.

I'm running inside a VM so this may cause some slowness.

Is there a way to optimize the running time?

```
Code:
    loader = unittest.TestLoader()
    print datetime.datetime.now()
    tests = loader.discover(
        start_dir='./tests/{0}'.format(suite),
        pattern=f_pattern, top_level_dir='.')
    print datetime.datetime.now()

Output:
    2017-11-10 23:20:10.668782
    2017-11-10 23:20:26.038204

    Running tests...
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------
    .........
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------
    Ran 9 tests in 0.134s
```

Comment: Hi, I had similar problem. In may case unit test used decorator skipIf.
`@unittest.skipIf( some_function() is None, 'None - skip', 'Check if None')` the `some_function` was extremely slow. This decorator was used in a few places so whole discovering process take several minutes.